# What is the better way to ng-repeat Big different data using custom directive?

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning Angular and trying to create big table with data from my git repositories using custom directive. But I don't know how to implement it, because the examples in different tutors and books usually simple but the object that I receive from $http is reeeeeally big and with nested objects. Here is my repo:
https://api.github.com/users/jotunnjs/repos

What I'm doing:

1. Get the data form the factory. I have an array with data. It's
   OK.
2. I create custom directive and get my array data in the local
   scope ( `scope: {data: "="}`).
3. Than I have a probleme. I use
       "`templateUrl`" where I create a table. Of course I think that do
       something like this it's not normal:

   > ```
   >   <table>
   >       <thead>
   >           <tr>
   >               <td>ID</td>
   >               <td>Name</td>
   >               <td>...</td>
   >                // here would be a lot of tag and it's difficult to maintain
   >           </tr>
   >       </thead>
   >           <tbody>
   >               <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
   >                   <td>{{item.id}}</td>
   >                   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
   >                   <td>{{item...}}</td>
   >               </tr>
   >           </tbody>
   >     </table>
   > ```

Couse It'll be a looooot of tags

I'm almost sure that I need to do like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in item in data">
            <td>{{key}}</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
                <td ng-repeat="i in item">{{i}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

But how cat I set the type of date in `<td>`?.  Because in the list you can find a types such as links, image, email and just string. Also how can I deal with the nested objects?

P.S. I know that the question is big and difficult, but if someone could help me to understand this situation it would be great! Please provide me with little example or some material where I can read it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solution, the first is keep the type of data as part of value. So Each property hold a complex object similar to following {value: "realValue", type: "stringOrTypeOfYourValue"}. Then you can modify your value according to its type.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data">
        <td ng-repeat="i in item">
             <span ng-show="i.type === Date"> {{i.value |date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</span>
             <span ng-show="i.type !== Date"> {{i.value}}</span>
         </td>
</tr>
```

Another solution would be to create a generic filter and try to understand the type of your values in the filter and apply corresponding filter according to your type. So for example:

```
yourApp.filter('formatValue', [function () {
    return function (value, dateFormat) {
      if (value instanceof Date) {
        return $filter("date")(value, dateFormat);
      } //You may add other conditions to handle such as formatting numbers etc.
      else {
        return value;
      }
    };
  }])
```